# How can I calculate the lengths of the sides of a polygon given the inside angles?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, trigonometry

Imagine I have a 4-sided irregular polygon which angles are a,b,c,d (clockwise from the topleft point) and sides A,B,C,D. Being A the side that connect the angles a and b, and so on.

Is there any way to solve this?

P.D: Sorry if it has been posted already, couldn't find it.

Comment: $S_{abcd}=S_{abc}\pm S_{adc}$

Comment: **You can't.** As said by random, knowing the angles does not give the lengths: think to a square that can be as large as you want !!!

Comment: A relaxed version of the question is, Can this polygon be determined up to similarity? I think it cannot without specific constraints on angles ABCD. For example, knowing all inner angles of a trapzoid cannot fix its edge length.